# Finding extrema of a function

Tags: calculus, optimization

Let $f(x)=\max_{t\in [0,1]}|t^2-tx|$. I find to find $\min_{x\in (0,1)}f(x)$. Any ideas on how to approach this problem?

Comment: In $(0,1)$, the function is differentiable, hence you should differentiate and find the roots of the derivative. At these points, minima and maxima occur.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $|t^2-tx| = |t(t-x)| = t|t-x|$ as $t$ is positive.To find the maximum of this function in $(0,1)$, we shall differentiate the function. 
$$
\frac{d}{dt}(t|(t-x)|) = |t-x| + t\bigg(\frac{|t-x|}{t-x}\bigg)
$$

Note that when the above is equal to zero, 
$$
|t-x| + t\bigg(\frac{|t-x|}{t-x}\bigg) = 0 \implies |t-x|\bigg(1+\frac{t}{t-x}\bigg) = 0
$$

Thus, either $t=x$, and here $|t^2-tx|$ is zero. In the other case, $$ 2t-x =0 \implies t=\frac{x}{2}
$$

Here, the function value is $\dfrac{x^2}{4}$, which is greater than zero. Now, all we have to make sure is that this, as a maximal value, is greater than both the values at zero and at one, because at these points the derivative may not be zero, but the function may be increasing beyond these points, hence we have to compare with them as well. Note that For $t=0$,  the function is zero, so there is nothing to worry. On the other hand, for $t=1$, you have a value $1-x$.  We have to see when $1-x > \frac{x^2}{4}$. Thankfully, this happens between $0$ and $2(\sqrt{2}-1)$. That is,
$$
f=
\begin{cases}
1-x \quad 0 \leq x \leq 2(\sqrt{2}-1) \\
\frac{x^2}{4} \quad 2(\sqrt{2}-1) < x \leq 1 
\end{cases}
$$

To find the minimum of this function, we will do it for both parts and take the minimum of the two. The first part is simple, namely that $1-x$ is decreasing, so it's minimum is $1-2(\sqrt{2}-1) = 3 - 2\sqrt{2}$. On the other hand, the function $\frac{x^2}{4}$ is an increasing function, hence  it's minimum is $4(\sqrt{2}-1)^2 = (\sqrt{2}-1)^2=3-2\sqrt{2}$ (the values are the same, because $f$ is a continuous function at the point $2(\sqrt{2}-1)$).

Hence, the answer is $3-2\sqrt{2}$.